# Function that selects a member of a struct and alters it's contents

Tags: c

So I am trying to write a function which takes a pointer to a struct, an element of the struct (representing a register) and an int which represents the bit in the register we want to set

My idea was

```
SET_GPIO_BIT(GPIO_TypeDef *PORT, volatile uint32_t reg, uint32_t bit) {
    PORT->reg |= (1 << bit);
}
```

where my struct in my header file looks like

```
typedef struct {
    volatile uint32_t    MODER;
    volatile uint32_t    OTYPER;
    //insert more registers here
    volatile uint32_t    BSRR;
} GPIO_TypeDef;
```

but then I get a (arm-none-eabi-gcc) compiler error:

```
error: 'GPIO_TypeDef {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'reg'
```

The basic idea is that I want to be able to write something like

```
SET_GPIO_BIT(GPIOA, BSRR, 7);
```

which will select the GPIO port A and set the seventh bit in the BSRR register (for example). Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Isn't `register` a keyword in C?  That aside, it looks like what you are asking how to do is pass in the name of a struct member to a function, correct?

Comment: yes I had it as "reg" in my original program but I changed it to "register" to try and make it more clear so I'll edit it. And yes, that is correct but with the caveat that the function can change the value of the struct member.

Comment: Sidenote: Any reason you don't use the BSRR, which exists for exactly that purpose? Your code is neither thread- nor interrupt safe. For more, RTF(ine)M and a beginner's C book, that's not related to embedded, but C language basics.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're looking for is text substitution, you need a macro for this:

```
#define SET_GPIO_BIT(port, reg, bit) ((port)->reg |= (1 << (bit)))
```

Alternately, since all registers are of the same type, you could instead use a function and pass in the address of the register in question depending on the situation:

```
void SET_GPIO_BIT(volatile uint32_t *reg, uint32_t bit) {
    *reg |= (1 << bit);
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
if (set_MODER) {
    SET_GPIO_BIT(&GPIOA->MODER, 7);
} else if (set_OTYPER) {
    SET_GPIO_BIT(&GPIOA->OTYPER, 7);
...
```

Comment: @EmbeddedDeveloper In cases like that yes, although it's best to avoid those types of transformations if possible.  See my update for an example which doesn't use macros.

Comment: @NominalAnimal In this case `reg` should not have parenthesis since it is the name of a field and would result in a syntax error if it did.

Comment: Although I posted a different "answer", this one answers the stated question quite perfectly, in my opinion. (Mine simply suggests a different approach to the underlying task, one that does not have the OP's stated problem at all.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the stated question; it is rather a suggestion to solve the underlying problem in a different way.

Rather than having the "registers" as separately named members in a structure, use an array instead:

```
enum {
    IOREG_MODE = 0,
    IOREG_OTYPE,
    /* All registers, in order */
    IOREG_COUNT
};

typedef struct {
    volatile uint32_t  ioreg[IOREG_COUNT];
} ioregs;
```

This lets you use either a macro,

```
#define IOREG_SET(port, reg, bit) (((port)->ioreg[reg]) |= (1u << (bit)))
#define IOREG_UNSET(port, reg, bit) (((port)->ioreg[reg]) &= ~(1u << (bit)))
#define IOREG_TOGGLE(port, reg, bit) (((port)->ioreg[reg]) ^= (1u << (bit)))
```

or a static inline function,

```
static inline uint32_t ioreg_set(regs *const port,
                                 const int reg,
                                 const unsigned char bit)
{
    return port->ioreg[reg] |= 1u << bit;
}

static inline uint32_t ioreg_unset(regs *const port,
                                   const int reg,
                                   const unsigned char bit)
{
    return port->ioreg[reg] &= ~(1u << bit);
}

static inline uint32_t ioreg_toggle(regs *const port,
                                    const int reg,
                                    const unsigned char bit)
{
    return port->ioreg[reg] ^= 1u << bit;
}
```

On any modern C compiler, both are equally fast, but the `static inline` functions provide compile-time type checking, and make it easier to debug cases where wrong data is output (via, for example, duplicating the writes to a debug text stream).

(If your I/O registers supports also 8-bit and/or 16-bit accesses, you can make the structure an union of arrays, with different static inline accessors depending on the size of the register.)